# Linear Motion and derivatives

Tags: calculus

A particle moving along a line has position $s(t)=t^4-18t^2m$ at time $t$ seconds. At which times does the particle pass through the origin? At which times is the particle instantaneously motionless (that is, it has zero velocity)?

Steps I'd take:

From what I understand, they have already given me an equation that described the position of the particle with respect to time. So I know that setting the equation to zero and solving for the roots will give me the solutions how how do I know that they go through the origin? Which I imagine is the coordinate pair $(0,0)$

For the second part of the question, I know that I have to find the derivative: $v(t)=4t^{ 3 }-36t$

And then I solve for its roots to find where the velocity is $0$:

$$v(t)=4t(t^{ 2 }-9)$$
$$v(t)=4t(t-3)(t+3)=0$$
$$t=3;\quad t=-3;\quad t=0$$

Please do not just give a direct answer. I would much rather get an explanation and hints to help me arrive at the correct solutions by myself.

Comment: It would   *pass through* the origin when it is at the origin and moving with non-zero speed.

Comment: Well then the solutions don't make sense to me

Comment: What are the solutions? (They should be $t=\pm\sqrt{18}=\pm3\sqrt2$ seconds.)

Comment: The solutions are that it passes though the origin when $t=0$ and when $t=3\sqrt { 2 } $

It is motionless when $t=0$ and when $t=3$

Comment: Then they're taking $t\ge0$ and interpreting "passing through" as "touching".

Comment: how is $t=3\sqrt { 2 } $ a solution for when it passes through the origin?

Comment: $t^4-18t^2=0\iff t^2(t^2-18)=0\iff t=0\ {\rm or}\ t^2-18=0$.

Comment: I understand that, but graphically, isn't the origin at $(0,0)$

Comment: You can take the particle to be moving along the $t$-axis (presumably). The "origin" is the point $0$ on this axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation for $s(t)$ has only one space component so it describe a motion on a straight line. The origin is the point with $s=0$ , so setting $s(t) =0$ (as you have done) you find the time when the position of the particle is the origin. The particle can stay ( or pass through the origin) at any time, and actually you find $t= 3\sqrt{2m}$ and $t=0$ solving the equation and supposing (as you have e physical problem) that $m,t >0$ (see that you forgot an $ m $ in all calculations).
I suppose you are confusing about what is the ''origin''. The term "origin" is referred to the space coordinate not to space-time.